# HTML5/Javascript Video Filtering

Tags: html

Is it possible to apply custom visual effects (such as grayscale) to the input stream of a  tag in HTML5/Javascript? My goal is to be able to display a filtered webcam's output to the user, but the user should be able to pick from a variety of filters, not just grayscale.

All help is greatly appreciated and I always accept an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do it is to grab each frame of a `video` element and process and then displaay it with `canvas`.  [Here's an example](http://html5inaction.com/app/ch8/index-6.html) I did recently for my book (warning: I know there are some issues with this example in IE9 currently), which used a greyscale filter from [HTML5 Rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/imagefilters/).  The main loop looks something like this, assume `video` is a reference to the element and `context` is a 2d canvas context, [`requestAnimFrame` comes from Paul Irish](http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/):

```
function draw() {
    if(video.paused || video.ended) return false;
    context.clearRect(0,0,720,480);
    context.drawImage(video,0,0,720,480);
    context.putImageData(grayscale(context.getImageData(0,0,720,480)),0,0);
    requestAnimFrame(draw);
}
```

The `getUserMedia()` function that Alex W mentions is only currently available in Opera and Chrome, you can read some blog posts about it and see some demos [here](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/getusermedia-access-camera-privacy-ui/).  Once you've got a media stream you can pipe it into a `video` element and do exactly the same thing as above.

Comment: This solution is OK, but the resulting image is blockier and has a smaller resolution than the original webcam output. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: @DanielH. Use whatever resolution `canvas` element you want.

Comment: This example is very slow, probably because it isn't GPU accelerated. is there any way to GPU accelerate visual effects on canvases?

Comment: @DanielH. You could try WebGL.

Comment: @DanielH. No, because hardware accelerated graphics is a browser/hardware feature, not an HTML5 feature.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is possible using the Get User Media API and WebGL:

http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/getusermedia.html

Here's an example (with links to lots of helpful resources):

http://neave.com/webcam/html5/